# How to extend given query for search by miles in Drupal 8?

Tags: drupal, geolocation, drupal-8, query-builder

I have given query for node and want to extend search by miles,

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
        ->condition('status', 1)
        ->condition('type', 'event')
        ->range(0, 10);
```

Location coming in array format using following query (installed geolocation module) and want to record using custom query not using internal search feature

```
$locationInArray = $node->get('location')->getValue();
```

Array value are like:

lat (latitude),
lng (longitude),
lat_sin (precalculated latitude sine),
lat_cos (precalculated latitude cosine),
lng_rad (precalculated radian longitude).

I am facing problem on lat long coming from another table so how to extend above query

I need distance wise search like 2 km/miles without help of drupal module 
because i have already implemented that but not fulfill my all needs so want to make custom search module.

here is given distance query but i am new in drupal so please help me to integrate given query in drupal my code.

SELECT
  id, (
    3959 * acos (
      cos ( radians(78.3232) )
      * cos( radians( lat ) )
      * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(65.3234) )
      + sin ( radians(78.3232) )
      * sin( radians( lat ) )
    )
  ) AS distance
FROM markers
HAVING distance < 30
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 0 , 20;

Comment: can you confirm that 'location' is not actually 'field_location' ?

Comment: field_location  location is coming from another table it's created from geolocation module

Comment: yes each field if drupal has own table. I just want to be sure that `$locationInArray = $node->get('location')->getValue();` is not `$locationInArray = $node->get('field_location')->getValue();`:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try with:

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
    ->condition('status', 1)
    ->condition('type', 'event')
    ->condition('location.lat', $your_value_lat)
    ->condition('location.lng', $your_value_lng)
    ->condition('location.lat_sin', $your_value_lat_sin)
    ->condition('location.lat_cos', $your_value_lat_cos)
    ->condition('location.lng_rad', $your_value_lng_rad)
    ->range(0, 10);
```

EDIT after question has been changed:

To use query directyl in drupal use `$query = \Drupal::database()->query()`

More: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/database-api

Your example should look something like that (I just swap one value with variable to show how this can be done):

```
$query = \Drupal::database()
  ->query("SELECT id, ( :example_variable * acos ( cos ( radians(78.3232) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(65.3234) ) + sin ( radians(78.3232) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < 30 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;",
[
  ':example_variable' => '3959'
]);
$result = $query->fetchAll();
```

Comment: It's working perfect but i want to calculate distance and based on lat long because i need distance wise search like within 2 km, 2 miles

Comment: Please check changes in question

Comment: I think database-api option need deep knowledge about drupal database structure whereas \Drupal::entityQuery  no need deep knowledge of structure any way to integrate distance query in \Drupal::entityQuery  way ?

Comment: AFAIK you can not do calculations with data as you wish with entityQuery.